# Mosaic Plot of Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a data set (called group2) that looks like this

```
        ticks var1   var2
11 2010-09-19    0     2
12 2010-09-20    1     4
16 2010-09-24    0     1
17 2010-09-26    1     1
18 2010-09-27    0     1
27 2010-10-06    0     1
29 2010-10-08    0     1
30 2010-10-10    1     1
31 2010-10-12    2     2
38 2010-10-19    0     2
39 2010-10-20    0     2
41 2010-10-22    0     2
42 2010-10-23    1     5
43 2010-10-24    2     3
44 2010-10-25    1     2
68 2010-11-19    3     4
83 2010-12-04    1     1
```

I wanted to make a mosaic plot such that the dates are on the x -axis and the categories (var1, var2) are on the vertical bars. 
I used `mosaicplot(group2[,2:3], col = c(7, 5), las = 3)`. but the top part of the image does not look right. [image]

I also want the dates to show at the top (vertically).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mosaicplot` needs a table (or a matrix) to be used as first argument. Here you can find a workaround for your setting

```
## Fake data set up
group2 <- data.frame(
    "ticks" = as.Date(c("2010-09-19","2010-09-20","2010-09-24")),
    "var1" =  c(0,1,0),
    "var2" = c(2,4,1))

## matrix creation
my.tab <- as.matrix(group2[,2:3])
rownames(my.tab) <- as.character(group2$ticks)
colnames(my.tab) <- c("var1","var2")

## plotting
mosaicplot(my.tab,
           col = c(7, 5),
           las = 3,
           main = "Mosaic plot")
```

With more columns should be better than this quick image:

[image: mosaic_plot_image]

You may also consider `las=2` (more readable).