# Mosaic Plot similar to R Cookbook

Tags: r, plot, cookbook, mosaic-plot

I want to create a mosaic plot like the one below from the R cookbook, but I cannot get it to plot the third dimension or format properly.

[Mosaic Plot from R Cookbook - what I am aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4FvJ.png)

I originally had my data in wide format and I could get a mosaic plot using (vcd) for a two by two table [mosaic plot for two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnkh9.png) but what I really wanted is all my columns plotted side by side with the same column to split the data in the y-direction, like the cookbook picture.

A similar issue to [this question but not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369434/mosaic-plot-of-data-frame) the same I tried this answer got error:

Error in observed - expected : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In loglin(x, expected, fit = TRUE, print = FALSE) :
NAs introduced by coercion

I transformed my data into long format but it is still not working.  I have approximately 17,000 rows by 3 columns all factored [long data factors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqkm1.png) each category within variable has the same number of case and control days but a different count of 1's and 0's which is what I am interested in comparing.

Currently my code is

```
mosaicplot(table(long$value, long$variable, long$nAP_CAT), col=c("darkblue","red"))
```

[producing a hideous plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulnFN.png)

And my data frame (df=long) sample looked like this in wide format

A tibble: 6 x 10

[first few rows and columns of df in wide format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGzJz.png) each column has two factor layers
I used melt(long, id.var="nAP_CAT") to make it a long df.

Ideally I want control Day v Case Day in the Y direction and variable categories in the x direction, two per variable category 1 and 0.  I would appreciate any help - not an experienced R programmer and stuck, thanks.

Comment: It's possible that you're getting the result you do because of the data and not that you're making the plot in the wrong way.  The example you are trying to emulate is a 2x2 for each group.  You've got a 13x2 (?) for each of 9 groups.  It might be that data sparsity is what's making it look bad.  If you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), perhaps we could help more.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When the data was in wide format I could make 9 separate 2x2 (col1 v, col2, col1 v. col3 etc) and piece them together manually, but I was hoping to make the process more elegant.  So I switched the data to long format hoping to do this in one call.

Comment: OK, I see now.  Without a some data (or ideally, a reproducible example) I'm not sure we can help all that much.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  I pasted the first few rows and columns in from Excel so you can get a better idea of what the data looks like, sorry it pasted as an image rather than data.

Comment: Please have a look at - [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  If we can't replicate what you're doing, we can't figure out how to do it better.  Pasting an image of your data is not something we can use.